# new font awesome icons not displaying in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I've downloaded the updated FA icons via plg_nsfontawesome_v1.6.zip and installed via Extension Manager into Joomla 3 site; installation appears successful.

All icons I have tried work ok EXCEPT the icons that are new in FA v4.3.0; for example, `fa-bus` and `fa-mercury` don't display.

Note I have been using FA for a while; and if I replace `fa-bus` with `fa-car` the car icon displays ok

Comment: Can you provide a link? It sounds like cache issue. Try to clean it.

Comment: If it's not a cache issue then I suggest you contact the developer of this extension.